# PHP Increase Letter Works, Decrease Does Not

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
$letter = 'D';
$letter++;
echo $letter; //outputs E
$letter--;
echo $letter; //outputs E
```

Why isn't the subtract function working?

Comment: Amazing. Didn't aware that `$letter++` actually changes D to E...

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php): `Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented`

Comment: I found the previous question and that documentation by googling "php decrement string". Please do a little research before posting questions that are likely to have simple answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of `ord()` and `chr()` functions:

```
$letter = 'D';
$val = ord($letter);
$val++;
echo chr($val);
$val--;
echo chr($val);
```